# Can we publish a message to an SNS topic using an AWS Lambda function backed by python?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm having 2 lambda functions in python. I want the first lambda function to publish a message to SNS topic after executing and this SNS topic after publishing the message should trigger the second lambda function. How can i do this, please help me out as I'm new to amazon-web-services

Comment: Can you add some code from what you have attempted so far? What you want to do is a fairly simple setup within AWS, for example you would use Boto3 in Python to send to SNS from a Lambda, and then subscribe a Lambda to that topic to handle the message, but I can't write all this from scratch for you

Answer (score -1):

Yes for sure you can do this, browse to Lambda trigger in top left corner of the Lambda function screen. Here you will all trigger options.

[image]